# Sum across columns while performing a transformation on them

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following dataset

```
test_df = game_df = read.table(text = "a_bias b_bias c_bias d_bias
dog dog cat cat
NA NA NA NA
cat cat cat cat
dog NA dog dog", header = T)
```

I'd like to create a new column called `dog_sum` that is equal to the total number of times the `dog` appears across all the columns that end with the word `bias`. Here's my current approach:

```
test_df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dog_sum = sum(across(ends_with("bias"), ~ifelse(. == "dog", 1, 0)), na.rm = T))
```

The issue is that this throws an error when the entire row consists of `NAs`. Is there a better way of solving this?

More generally, I'd like to mutate new columns for every column matched by `ends_with("bias")`, and this new column should be set to 1 if it contains `dog` and 0 otherwise. So, the end result would be to have four columns named `a_bias_dog`, `b_bias_dog`, etc. that are set to 1 if "dog" is present for that specific row, and 0 otherwise.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do this with `rowSums` as a vectorized approach and should be faster than `rowwise/sum`

```
library(dplyr)
test_df %>% 
   mutate(dog_sum = rowSums(across(ends_with('bias')) == 'dog',
       na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
   a_bias b_bias c_bias d_bias dog_sum
1    dog    dog    cat    cat       2
2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>       0
3    cat    cat    cat    cat       0
4    dog   <NA>    dog    dog       3
```

---

If we want to generate new columns, use

```
test_df %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with('bias'), ~ +(. %in% 'dog'), .names = "{.col}_dog"))
```

-output

```
   a_bias b_bias c_bias d_bias a_bias_dog b_bias_dog c_bias_dog d_bias_dog
1    dog    dog    cat    cat          1          1          0          0
2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>          0          0          0          0
3    cat    cat    cat    cat          0          0          0          0
4    dog   <NA>    dog    dog          1          0          1          1
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to apply a function in this way with `rowwise()`, you can use `c_across`. But when the function you want to apply rowwise is `sum`, you're better off using `rowSums` as in the other answers.

```r
test_df = game_df = read.table(text = "a_bias b_bias c_bias d_bias
dog dog cat cat
NA NA NA NA
cat cat cat cat
dog NA dog dog", header = T)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

test_df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dog_sum = sum(c_across(ends_with('bias')) == 'dog', na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   a_bias b_bias c_bias d_bias dog_sum
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <int>
#> 1 dog    dog    cat    cat          2
#> 2 <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         0
#> 3 cat    cat    cat    cat          0
#> 4 dog    <NA>   dog    dog          3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use rowsums(condition). If your data is exactly like you showed, akruns answer will do the trick. In case you actually want to count columns that "contain" the character 'dog' as part of a more complex character, you can use `str_detect`, or, if you expect multiple 'dog' matches in some rows, we can use `str_count`.

```
test_df %>% mutate(dog_sum=rowSums(across(ends_with('bias'), ~str_detect('dog'))))

#OR

test_df %>% mutate(dog_sum=rowSums(across(ends_with('bias'), ~str_count('dog'))))
```

If you want to create a column that is either one or zero pending on having `any` dogs, you can use:

```
df %>% mutate(any_dogs=if_any(ends_with('bias'), ~str_detect('dog')))
```